# How can I pass header parameters to a submit call for an Ext.form.Panel object?

Tags: forms, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to download a file and need to pass along authentication in the header. According to other discussions on stackoverflow and the sencha forums, I need `standardSubmit: true` to get the download to work, but when I add it, the headers do not get passed along in the request!

Why is this? How can I force it to pass the header?

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    standardSubmit: true,
    url: url,
    method: method
});

form.submit({
    headers: {
        Authorization: authToken
    },
    target: '_blank', // Avoids leaving the page.
    params: params
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `target` property from? I can see `headers` in the docs but not `target` http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action-cfg-headers

Comment: The code is from a discussion on stackoverflow about downloading files through Ajax requests in sencha touch. I'll try removing it.

Comment: Unfortunately removing it did not fix the issue

Comment: fyi target from StandardSubmit - https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.action.StandardSubmit

Answer (score 0):

Form submit does not support headers. Use Ajax request

```
if(form.isValid()) {
    var data = form.getValues(false, true);
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'your_url',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
            token: 'myToken'
        },
        jsonData: { myParam: 'value' },
        callback: function (options, success, response) {
            // done
        }
    });
}
```